# submit form can not access method in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

When I submit form in view, I can't access that in controller.

**View create.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('content')



    <form method="POST" action="posts">

        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter title">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
```

**Controller PostController**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return $request->all();
}
```

I want to access the form data, in `PostController` in the store method and once I click submit, it not giving the result.

I have route: `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController')` and I am posting to this route/url, as `action="posts"`. In `Route` I have used resource and in `method="post"`

Does it matter? What can I do?

Comment: Put `{{ csrf_field() }}` after opening form tag (after `... action="posts">`. And make sure you're posting to the correct url.

Comment: in php artisan route:list,      the uri to be used to store method is: posts. that's why i wrote the action="posts".  but i can't get to that....

Comment: i have route:     Route::resource('posts', 'PostController').           and i am posting to this route/url, as action="posts".       in Route i have used resource and in method="post"...... does it matter ????? what can i do ???

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the action

```
Route::post('post', 'PostController@store');
```

Comment: He's using resourceful routing 

Route::resource('posts', 'PostController')

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but may be it's because of `url` and not included `csrf_field()`. Try changing it to:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('posts') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Enter title">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

or you may use `route('posts.store ')` instead of `url('posts')`